# Maximum Constraints Satisfaction of Linear Programming

Tags: constrained-optimization, linear-programming

The question I need to solve is to maximize the satisfied constraints in linear programming.

To be more specific, Suppose I have an infeasible LP problem, my goal now, is to find the maximum number of the constraints which I can satisfy.

Put in a formulation way:

$$
\max \sum_{i=1}^K x_i,\\ \text{s.t.}\   
\mathrm{diag}(x)(A-b) y \geq 0
$$

And I have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$

If $y$ is in a finite domain, it would be maximum satisfiability (MAX-SAT), which is proved to be an NP-hard problem.
However, for a linear program problem, I cannot find if it's NP-hard or polynomial-time solvable.

If there is any research about this, please let me know.

Comment: Your notation is unclear (or perhaps simply wrong)  Is the original set of constraints (of which you want to satisfy as many as possible) $Ay \geq b$?  Are the $x_{i}$ variables  discrete 0-1 variables?

Comment: Yes, the infeasible set is $Ay \geq b$. And yes, $x_i$ are discrete 0-1 variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugging purposes, it's helpful to identify small subsets of infeasible constraints in an LP formulation- an Irreducible Infeasible Subset (IIS) is a subset of the constraints that are infeasible and such that removing any constraint from the IIS results in a feasible set of constraints.  This is doable in polynomial time and fairly fast in practice, but it is not the same as finding a maximum feasible subsystem.

This problem of finding a maximum subset of feasible constraints in an infeasible LP is NP-Hard.  See

Amaldi, Edoardo, Marc E. Pfetsch, and Leslie E. Trotter Jr. "On the maximum feasible subsystem problem, IISs and IIS-hypergraphs." Mathematical Programming 95, no. 3 (2003): 533-554.

Comment: You save my day. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Artermi, if that answer your question you could accept the answer.

Comment: I found a similar problem. Do you know any polynomial algorithm for the case of 2D?
[Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6765/maximum-feasible-subsystem-problem-maxfs-in-2-variables)